# JQuery: Argument of type Node[] is not assignable to Element

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have some old code that used to work, but now won't compile (typescript). The code is this:

```
elem.replaceWith($.parseHTML(html));
```

The idea is that I have some HTML from a reliable source, and I want to replace elem (Which is a JQuery object) with the parsed version of that code. However, I get an error saying:

```
Argument of type 'Node[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Element | Document | Text | Comment | Element[] | DocumentFragment | JQuery<Node> | ((this: HTMLElement, index: number, oldhtml: string) => string | ... 6 more ... | JQuery<...>)'.
```

This used to work just fine, but now does not, presumably since something changed either in JQuery (version 3) or the DefinitelyTyped bindings.

How can I achieve the goal of converting that HTML in a string into a type I can insert into an element?

Comment: we need more code. hopefully a fully reproducible example.

Comment: but as far as I know jquery returns an array of elements and you have to pull one of them... maybe like this $("some selector")[0]